# how to retrieve image from server side by using attribute add

Tags: asp.net

how to at retrive a image at server side and display on client side? any thing wrong?  my picture is store at project. anyone have any idea to help me thx. i'm try alot solution but it still cant work

---

```
 <asp:Image ID="rating" runat="server" />
 rating.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url('Image/Icon/Rank/rating1.gif')");
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That code doesn't retrieve anything. Also, why would you want an `<img style="background-image:url('Image/Icon/Rank/rating1.gif')"/>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [src attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) of [image tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

```
rating.Attributes.Add("src", "Image/Icon/Rank/rating1.gif");
```